# What does it mean 0 0.000e+00 in statistical test in R?

Tags: r, p-value

I can`t find any information about what does it mean this value of p-value

- 0 0.000e+00
  If somebody can help me with this?

I did Post Hoc to Permutation Anova - with this code:

```
SJ4100__ = pairwisePermutationTest(CTWF~Worm_Names, data=SJ4100_GPI, method = "fdr")
```

and that what i have:

```
SJ4100__
        Comparison    Stat   p.value  p.adjust
1   ev - spg-7 = 0  -9.475 2.663e-21 5.326e-21
2      ev - 75 = 0   4.252 2.122e-05 3.031e-05
3     ev - 363 = 0   9.191         0 0.000e+00
4     ev - 353 = 0   8.203  2.22e-16 3.700e-16
5   spg-7 - 75 = 0   10.29         0 0.000e+00
6  spg-7 - 363 = 0   13.78         0 0.000e+00
7  spg-7 - 353 = 0   13.13         0 0.000e+00
8     75 - 363 = 0   4.096 4.201e-05 5.251e-05
9     75 - 353 = 0    3.22  0.001284 1.427e-03
10   363 - 353 = 0 -0.9382    0.3481 3.481e-01
```

Comment: Isn't it just 0, but in scientific notation?

Comment: non-numbers being parsed as numbers.?

Comment: If you have such low p-values and their actual magnitude is important, you need to consider precision of floating point numbers and operations.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the distribution function used, the p-value is calculated from the Stat value as follows (example for normal distrubution, other distributions such as t or chi will have different p-values):

```
Stat <- 10.29
2*pnorm(-Stat)
```

On the summary output, such low values are then rounded to 0. Try this calculation for some of the given Stat values and you will see that below a certain value the output is presented as `0.000e+00`.